# What does it mean if SMART test reports Unknown_Attribute FAILING_NOW?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, smart

I have a hard drive (HUH721010ALE601) which is reporting a failing SMART test, but I'm having a hard time interpreting what it means. The failure looks to be with attribute 45, which is labelled "Unknown_Attribute". What does this attribute refer to? I don't see it listed in listed in the [HDD's manual (pdf)](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/data-center-drives/ultrastar-sata-series/product-manual-ultrastar-dc-hc510-sata-oem-spec.pdf) and looking through here and elsewhere I'm not seeing any references to the same SMART attribute. Obviously I'm not comfortable with a drive reporting an imminent failure, but I'm having a hard time understanding what the specific issue is.

```
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.5.11-8-pve] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     HUH721010ALE601
Serial Number:    7PKPR6KC
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 251f425af
Firmware Version: LHGL0003
User Capacity:    10,000,831,348,736 bytes [10.0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Feb  3 11:10:56 2024 MST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  73) The previous self-test completed having
                                        a test element that failed and the test
                                        element that failed is not known.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (   93) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   133   133   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       100
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   175   175   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       315 (Average 437)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       197
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   128   128   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       34111
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       41
 22 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   100   100   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
 45 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   001   001   001    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 16711680
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       678
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       678
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   150   150   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 21/55)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3956502114338
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3609383775396

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%     34111         0
# 2  Vendor (0x70)       Completed without error       00%     33962         -
# 3  Vendor (0x71)       Completed without error       00%     33962         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "Unknown_Attribute" are not documented, which is why they
are labelled this way.

For attribute 22,
I found documentation in Wikipedia
[Self-Monitoring, Analysis, and Reporting Technology (S.M.A.R.T., often written as SMART)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology):

> 22 Current Helium Level
> Specific to He8 drives from HGST. This value
> measures the helium inside of the drive specific to this manufacturer.
> It is a pre-fail attribute that trips once the drive detects that the
> internal environment is out of specification.

The Backblaze post
[SMART 22 Is a Gas, Gas, Gas](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/smart-22-is-a-gas-gas-gas/)
for HGST Ultrastar He8 hard drives has similar information:

> The attribute highlighted in red is SMART 22, and we had never seen that one before. We researched this “Unknown_Attribute” and couldn’t find anything online so we asked the HGST folks. They responded by saying that attribute 22 is the status of the helium in a drive. It is a pre-fail attribute that trips once the drive detects that the internal environment is out of specification. They did not share the amount of helium in a given drive or the “trip points” related to the amount of helium although there is a normalized threshold value of “25” listed.

As the Backblaze values for the attribute are the same as yours,
I think you can ignore this warning.

For attribute 45, I haven't found any documentation at all.
However, all your critical SMART attributes have perfect values,
so I would ignore this one too.

My conclusion is that your disk is in perfect health, although
it's a good idea, for any disk, to keep an eye on the SMART
attributes, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's good to hear. It's in an array that can tolerate a failure, so I'll just keep it going for now while keeping an eye on it.